# What is a proper way to get a Jacobian matrix in Zygote (Julia)?

Tags: julia, gradient

I'm trying to get a Jacobian matrix for L, with a vector q and q^dot, but couldn't get a proper matrix. Could anyone help me to get the matrix by using this Zygote package correctly? FYI, I'm totally noob to this differentiable programming world. Any references to study DP or AD from scratch would be also welcomed. Thank you :)

```
using LinearAlgebra
using Zygote
using DifferentialEquations

## CONSTANTS
g = 9.81;
## PARAMS
m₁ = 1;
m₂ = 1;
l₁ = 1;
l₂ = 1;

## TEST SAMPLE
θ₁=30*pi/180;
θ₂=15*pi/180;
ω₁=2.;
ω₂=1.;

q1 = [θ₁;θ₂]
q̇1 = [ω₁;ω₂]

##
M(q)=[(m₁+m₂)*l₁^2              l₁*l₂*m₂*cos(q[1]-q[2]);
      l₁*l₂*m₂*cos(q[1]-q[2])   m₂*l₂^2];

U(q) = g*(m₁*(-l₁*cos(q[1])) +
          m₂*(-l₁*cos(q[1])-l₂*cos(q[2])));

T(q,q̇) = ((1/2).*q̇'*M(q)*q̇)[1]
V(q,q̇) = U(q)

L(q,q̇) = T(q,q̇) - V(q,q̇);

## gradient((a, b) -> a*b, 2, 3)
∂L_∂q(f,q,q̇) = gradient(f,q,q̇)[1]; #Partial Diff. w/ q Vector
∂L_∂q̇(f,q,q̇) = gradient(f,q,q̇)[2]; #Partial Diff. w/ q̇ Vector
∂L_∂q(L,q1,q̇1) #OKAY
∂L_∂q̇(L,q1,q̇1) #OKAY

∂∂L_∂q∂q̇(f,q,q̇) = gradient(((q, q̇) -> ∂L_∂q(f,q,q̇)),q,q̇)[2];
∂∂L_∂q∂q̇(L,q1,q̇1) #ERROR
```

Answer (score 1):

Zygote over Zygote won't currently work, so I would recommend Tracker over Zygote for this:

```
using LinearAlgebra
using Zygote
using DifferentialEquations
import Tracker

## CONSTANTS
g = 9.81;
## PARAMS
m₁ = 1;
m₂ = 1;
l₁ = 1;
l₂ = 1;

## TEST SAMPLE
θ₁=30*pi/180;
θ₂=15*pi/180;
ω₁=2.;
ω₂=1.;

q1 = [θ₁;θ₂]
q̇1 = [ω₁;ω₂]

##
M(q)=[(m₁+m₂)*l₁^2              l₁*l₂*m₂*cos(q[1]-q[2]);
      l₁*l₂*m₂*cos(q[1]-q[2])   m₂*l₂^2];

U(q) = g*(m₁*(-l₁*cos(q[1])) +
          m₂*(-l₁*cos(q[1])-l₂*cos(q[2])));

T(q,q̇) = ((1/2).*q̇'*M(q)*q̇)[1]
V(q,q̇) = U(q)

L(q,q̇) = T(q,q̇) - V(q,q̇);

## gradient((a, b) -> a*b, 2, 3)
∂L_∂q(f,q,q̇) = gradient(f,q,q̇)[1]; #Partial Diff. w/ q Vector
∂L_∂q̇(f,q,q̇) = gradient(f,q,q̇)[2]; #Partial Diff. w/ q̇ Vector
∂L_∂q(L,q1,q̇1) #OKAY
∂L_∂q̇(L,q1,q̇1) #OKAY

∂∂L_∂q∂q̇(f,q,q̇) = Tracker.gradient(((q, q̇) -> ∂L_∂q(f,q,q̇)),q,q̇)[2];
∂∂L_∂q∂q̇(L,q1,q̇1)
```

Comment: Now, I get this error message from the last line, which is ∂∂L_∂q∂q̇(L,q1,q̇1). "MethodError: no method matching."
Seems like the Tracker is old and now replaced with the Zygote (https://github.com/FluxML/Tracker.jl).
Are there any docs for the Tracker package I can refer to?

Comment: I'm using Julia Version 1.3.1 (2019-12-30) by the way. Please let me know if I should revert back to the previous versions to properly use the Tracker. Thank you :)

Comment: Tracker is fine on 1.3. What was the error message you got?

Comment: I got the following message when I try to evaluate the ∇q∇q̇L @ (q1,q̇1), which is ∂∂L_∂q∂q̇(L,q1,q̇1):
MethodError: no method matching (::Zygote.var"#1276#1277"{TrackedArray{…,Adjoint{Tracker.TrackedReal{Float64},Array{Tracker.TrackedReal{Float64},1}}},TrackedArray{…,Array{Float64,1}}})(::Tracker.TrackedReal{Tracker.TrackedReal{Float64}})
Closest candidates are:
  #1276(!Matched::AbstractArray{T,1} where T) at /Users/seongheonlee/.julia/packages/Zygote/ApBXe/src/lib/array.jl:295
(::Zygote.var"#3252#back#1278"{Zygote.var"#1276#1277"{TrackedArray{…,Adjoint{Tracker.
(...the rest omitted...)